# Right side of piston-chest room not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

[image]

I am trying to make a chest room similar to Etho's where you walk on pressure plates and all the chests come through stairs. I was stoked that I got one side working, but the other wouldn't do a thing. I'm using a T flip flop for it. I'll put some screen shots if you want. Thanks.

[image: See how only one side of the red stone is functional? see how only some of the chests are available?]

[image: that is the tflip flop]

Comment: Yes, screenshots would be very helpful.

Comment: Added some screen shots. Very, very disappointed with both stack overflow and this gaming thing. come on stack exchange! I mean like adding photos is tough. The people are great though.

Comment: I agree, it is far from dummy-proof. But if you learn how Markdown works, then it starts to make sense and becomes easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at your screenshot (which is very helpful to have - sorry you had trouble uploading them) it appears that the repeater between the lit redstone and the unlit redstone is facing the wrong way, assuming that the signal from the t-flip-flop comes in right on the other side of the glowstone (which is the only way I could imagine the redstone could behave the way it does in the picture).

Also, there's a tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBm4vdDn_Xw) which might help. I used this to build my replica, though you may have already found it.

Comment: Thanks. I can't test it out right now but I will later. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Make sure all the repeaters on that side are facing away from the rear/center, as well.

Comment: Repeater direction error has killed more than one of my designs....

Comment: Thanks man! That worked perfectly. You have no idea how much I love you right now. Keep on being a boss.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score -2):

Try puting a repeater between the right and the left side so the right wil be triggered by the left side.

Comment: This is way too confusing without a screenshot..

Comment: I have added screenshots and there is a repeater there.

Comment: i ment linking up the working side with the now working side. just extend the redstone so it reaches all the way up to the end of the right side